# GoogleWebRTC Audio Video Calling iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, voip, webrtc-ios

I want to develop one audio-video calling application. So, I have decided to use Google WebRTC, so Google WebRTC is good for calling functionality?. Is Google WebRTC support to Conference Calling?. If it is not, then what are the different limitation of Google WebRTC? Please suggest me another calling SDK's for iOS Swift.

Comment: Did you have any solution for Audio Video call using GoogleWebRTC?